# pulseaudio - stuttering - what this log says? (alsa.sink.c: Underrun!)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a problem with sound which sometimes crackling/stuttering. It happend on `Ubuntu 18.04` but I reinstalled to `Ubuntu 19.04` and the same thing happens.

I've found these records. It logs only when the crackling sound appears so it has to be an answer here but I don't know what does it mean.

I've killed `pulseaudio` and run it manually:

```
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=stderr --log-level=4
```

Can you give me some hints?

```
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Scheduling delay of 144.70 ms > 65.99 ms, you might want to investigate this to improve latency...
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Underrun!
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Increasing minimal latency to 86.00 ms
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Latency set to 86.00ms
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: hwbuf_unused=50368
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: setting avail_min=13475
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: max_request changed, trying to update from 35000 to 38528.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: Notifying client about increased tlength
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Latency set to 86.00ms
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: hwbuf_unused=50368
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: setting avail_min=13475
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: Implicit underrun of 'Playback'
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Requested to rewind 15168 bytes.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Limited to 14784 bytes.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: before: 3696
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: after: 3696
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Rewound 14784 bytes.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] sink.c: latency = 1345
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 14784 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] source.c: Processing rewind...
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Underrun!
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Increasing wakeup watermark to 75.99 ms
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Underrun!
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Increasing minimal latency to 96.00 ms
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Latency set to 96.00ms
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: hwbuf_unused=48604
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: setting avail_min=13034
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: max_request changed, trying to update from 38528 to 42056.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: Notifying client about increased tlength
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Latency set to 96.00ms
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: hwbuf_unused=48604
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: setting avail_min=13034
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: Implicit underrun of 'Playback'
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Requested to rewind 16932 bytes.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Limited to 16516 bytes.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: before: 4129
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: after: 4129
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Rewound 16516 bytes.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] sink.c: latency = 1318
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 16516 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] source.c: Processing rewind...
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Scheduling delay of 195.31 ms > 75.99 ms, you might want to investigate this to improve latency...
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Underrun!
I: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Increasing wakeup watermark to 85.99 ms
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: Implicit underrun of 'Playback'
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] protocol-native.c: Requesting rewind due to end of underrun.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Requested to rewind 16932 bytes.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Limited to 16580 bytes.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: before: 4145
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: after: 4145
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Rewound 16580 bytes.
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] sink.c: Processing rewind...
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] sink.c: latency = 1510
D: [alsa-sink-ALC892 Analog] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 16580 bytes on render memblockq.
```

I've found related bug maybe:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=859758

Comment: Is the system under a high load (CPU or I/O) when this happens, or does it also happen when simply playing some audio while nothing else is using much resources?

Comment: @JanC There is nothing long term running with high CPU usage when it happens BUT I can say for sure that everytime this happens, pulseaudio daemon jumps to let's say 60% - but it is almost unnoticeable - it remains like a half second or so... so if it happens, until you open terminal and check top/htop, you don't see it anymore. But I waited and can say for 100% that it jumps in CPU load. Maybe it's even 100% cPU for a moment but refresh rate of HTOP can't catch that...